# Bluetooth Low Energy with native code on Windows 10

Tags: uwp, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, wdk

I have a native win32 application targeting Window 7 and on. Recently, I was required to add Bluetooth Low Energy support, but only for Windows 10.

The BLE-GATT functionality I need is:

- Detect device connection/disconnection (i.e. get an event or callback when either occures)
- Write some characteristics on the device
- Get notifications (again, via an event or a callback), from the device

**What is the best way to achieve this on Windows 10?**

So far I've looked into:

- [Windows Drivers Kit (WDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt492499(v=vs.85).aspx) - the [sample code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/bad452cb-4fc2-4a86-9b60-070b43577cc9/is-there-a-simple-example-desktop-programming-c-for-bluetooth-low-energy-devices?forum=wdk) works, but I couldn't find any way to detect device connection/disconnection.
- [Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-low-energy-overview) - has a slick API, but I can't find how to integrate with native win32 (possible only via COM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use Bluetooth radio notifications to get notified when a device connects / disconnects. See GUID_BLUETOOTH_RADIO_IN_RANGE at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362912(v=vs.85).aspx and look at the BDIF_CONNECTED field.
2. It's not specifically a UWP library. Just Google how to use WinRT API with C++.

Comment: tried #1, but I'm stuck: If I call `CreateFile` with my BLE service GUID, the device connects, but **only after I try to make a GATT access (enable notifications)**. However, I don't get any notifications when it disconnects/reconnect. If I call `CreateFile` with `GUID_BTHPORT_DEVICE_INTERFACE`, I can't call GATT methods, so Windows, as a BLE Central, does not initiates a connection. Any suggestion?

Comment: The windows ble api is a bit strange. It will only try to keep the device connected as long as you have a registered notification. Or it will connect temporarily when you do other operations and then disconnect.

Comment: Strange indeed. The problem is that for this specific device I have to enable notifications in order to receive any data. So if the device was turned off and then on again, and then reconnects, I have no way of knowing it. Anything else I can do besides polling?

Comment: Aren't you getting any events at all on the Radio device?

Comment: I didn't realize I need to register for messages from the **local** BLE radio, i.e. the one in the PC, not the remove. Makes sense, really :)